# Pydev Django al reiniciar servidor no recarga cambios hechos en html

Tags: python, django, eclipse, xampp

Buen día, apenas estoy iniciando en el desarrollo de python web, estoy usando Eclipse y trabajo con Pydev,  estoy trabajando con un proyecto descargado desde una repo donde mi tarea es crear un formulario e integrarlo a la plantilla que se utiliza en el proyecto, el problema esta en que mis cambios no se muestran al cargar mi aplicación solo se muestra la plantilla y los archivos estaticos.
Estuve realizando pruebas y vi al principio que mis cambios si se recargaban pero solo cuando reiniciaba mi equipo pero al intentar hacer cambios y recargar mi navegador de nuevo los cambios se revertian a solo mostrar los archivos estaticos y la plantilla, he borrado las cookies, intento cargar la pagina con ctrl-F5 y no muestra ningun cambio.
Anexo algo de información sobre el proyecto:
settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portal',
    'panel',
    'dashboard',
    'establishment',
    'device',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Archivo html donde estoy trabajando:

```
{% extends "library/base.html" %}

{% load staticfiles %}

{% block div_content %}

<!-- EL contenido de mi form -->

{% endblock %}

{% block script_panel %}

{% endblock script_panel %}
```

Por ultimo algo que tambien note es que al reiniciar MYSQL tambien a veces me permitia ver los cambios en navegador (estoy usando XAMPP para MYSQL)
Esperaria que alguien me pudiera ayudar ya que la verdad llevo bastante rato buscando si encontrar solución a esto.
Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Si pudieras dar más detalles, quizá compartir el repo, o colocar la view que hace el render de ese HTML, sería más útil, también puedes intentar ejecutar el runserver directamente desde la terminal para ver si el problema es de Eclipse o pydev, o quizá en view no estas pasando las variables en el context

Comment: Puedes colocar el contenido de la template 'library/base.html'